# OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder Deprecated

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm following the developer documentation on Facebook to post a custom story onto the user's timeline [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/open-graph).

When it comes to actually displaying the dialog to the user, I am using the exact code that they are as you can see below.

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "books.reads", "book")
```

However, I am getting `is deprecated`. That doesn't make sense to me, considering it's in the current documentation but anyway. Now I've tried to find what to replace it with in [this part](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder/) of the documentation but there's nothing that says about it being deprecated.

Anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you, I'm currently struggling with the Facebook Open Graph API and the outdated, or simply missing, documentation.

I've found that instead of using :

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "namespace_of_your_fp_app.action_name", "graph_object_name")
```

You should create your OpenGraphAction by giving it's type :

```
OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
action.setType("namespace_of_your_fp_app.action_name");
action.setProperty("graph_object_name", graphObject);
```

Then, use this to create your ShareDialog

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "graph_object_name").build();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This does work. Just a shame it doesn't give us this method in the codumentation to use instead

Comment: Yeah... I'm trying to find a way to put a list of "GeoPoint" in my graph object in order to use the Map Layout with a path on it (like Runtastic does) and I can't find any doc talking about that! Anyway, good luck :)

Comment: I am doing exactly the same thing. I have actually submitted a bug report about it https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/820798267972000/.
 
Documentation-wise the only bit about it is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories#attachment.

I have done it before but I can't get it to work again!

Comment: Sweet! I've finally found someone trying to do the same thing!! I've also decided to use the HTML way of setting the graph object in the OpenGraphAction because it looks like using setProperty("route:latitude") in my OpenGraphObject as many times as I have a GPS record do not work... The thing is that I generate the graph object HTML file on my server "on the fly" and pass it to the OpenGraphAction, but now, the ShareDialog just appears for a second and closes... If you have any advice or web link to give me in order to understand how I should do, that would be great!

Comment: Lets take this to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62265/map-layout-custom-facebook-story